# what is `tput rmam`

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, unix

`tput rmam` turns off line wrapping on the terminal.app

I always forget this command, because I never figured out what `rmam` stands for. Anybody knows?

Comment: For more technical details try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147609/who-does-the-linewrap-and-how-to-deactivate

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810483/unable-to-turn-off-automatic-margins-by-termcap-in-mac

Answer (score 2):

From section 5 of the terminfo manual page (`terminfo(5)`):

```
rmam    turn of automatic margins
```

You could think of it as: ReMove Automatic Margins.

Comment: smam stands for?

Comment: @joshsverns `man 5 terminfo`> Enter `/`(search) and `smam` (so `/smam`) which will reveal: *enter_am_mode        **smam**        SA        turn on automatic margins*

Comment: still dunno what the S is for in smam

Comment: @joshverns: It might not stand for anything, but just be the next letter after `r`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [terminfo standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/terminfo.html), most capabilities starting with `sm..` are documented as either "Start Mode ..." or "Enter Mode ..." or "Set ..." so `smam` means either Start Mode Automatic Margins or Set Mode Automatic Margins

`rm..` is indeed a bit more mysterious. In the same place most capabilities starting with `rm..` are documented as "Exit Mode ..." so maybe `rm...` stands for `Reset Mode ...` or `Return from Mode ...`?

Also interesting:

```
tput smam | od -t a
0000000  esc   [   ?   7   h   
tput rmam | od -t a
0000000  esc   [   ?   7   l
```

Comment: the name rm might come from the `rm` command that removed files

Comment: I doubt it because it wouldn't match `sm`. The answer might be in some old terminfo source code.